# Java scan.nextLine won't scan the entire String, only the first line

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

EDIT: Sorry, I changed the code to reflect my problem.  I have tried using scan.nextLine() and it is not working, which is strange to me.

I am trying to scan in the following String and save into a String variable called "tweet." :

"#typ offer; #det free essential supplies 4 evacs pets.; #loc
2323 55th st, boulder; #lat 40.022; #lng -105.226;"

However when I print the final tweet string, it only saves the first line, all the way to #loc.  It doesn't include the 2323 55th st, boulder; #lat 40.022; #lng -105.226;" part of the string.   Is there something besides nextLine() I should be using?? Here is my code and output.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String tweet = null;
    String type, detail, location, latitude, longitude = null;

    int start, finish = 0;

    tweet = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(tweet);
```

The output that I get is: "#typ offer; #det free essential supplies 4 evacs pets.; #loc

However it is missing the second part of the string. Probably a super easy fix, but thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: Your title says nextLine, your code says next. Which one is it?

Comment: Checkout hasNextLine and nextLine from Java docs. You have to also decide when to stop i.e. stop at second line or 3rd line.

Comment: sorry, I meant to put scan.nextLine() in my code, and it is not working with this, which is confusing to me.

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Are you sure you are inputting that exact String?

Comment: I found out the problem.  I was copying and pasting the input tweet from a pdf, and it was putting everything into two separate lines.  When I manually typed in the tweet into eclipse myself instead of pasting it from the pdf, it worked correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Don't chaange the whole question after everyone answered. Because everyone answers become irrelevant. Instead of that add as **Edit** or **update** at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `scan.next();`, not `scan.nextLine()`. Maybe that's a typo, but if that's the code, try changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tweet = scan.nextLine();
```

It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

`scan.next();` method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner(until it hit the first space it will end).

Output will be:

```
"#typ
```

you need to use `scan.nextLine();`,

If you use `nwxtLine()` output will be:

```
"#typ offer; #det free essential supplies 4 evacs pets.; #loc 2323 55th st, boulder; #lat 40.022; #lng -105.226;"
```

read [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: from the question it should be clear that scan.next() could not give the error OP provided.

Comment: @ThijsSteel He has changed his question

Answer (score 0):

You are using `next()` that will give you the next token. What you should use is `nextLine()` that will give you all the line.

EDIT:

You said that using `nextLine()` is not working, that's weird because it works. Are you sure you are not copying and pasting the sentence? Maybe it has a `CRLF`. Try writing the sentence.